# Which whiteboard/canvas app with custom background and color options

Tags: software, videos

I'm looking for a PC software whiteboard application that allows for custom RGB background colors and custom RGB pen colors.  Most I've seen offer only a handful of color choices for the pen.

Lucidspark, an online app, for example, offers custom RGB pen colors, but does not allow the canvas color to be changed.

This is to be used for my lecture/chalk-talk recordings for undergrad higher-ed math.

I prefer something local to my computer, and as cheap as possible, of course.  Besides custom color features I think only pen thickness options would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The free version of myViewBoard works.  It allows for custom background and pen colors.  You can download it as a PC app or use it online as a web app.